# How to take RadioButtonList.SelectedIndex in to an array of Ints?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindex

I simply wants to Take SelectedIndex of radiobuttonlist into an int array on OnSelectedIndexChanged event. I tried following code but won't worked:

i make an array like this:

```
int[] correctAnswers = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 }; and i tried this as well:     
int[] correctAnswers = new int[100];

//SelectionChangeEvent    
protected void rbAnswers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{               
    int j = rbAnswers.SelectedIndex;                
    correctAnswers.SetValue(j, i); //or correctAnswers[i] = j;        
}
```

I'm making a online test system in .Net. I'm changing question in label and answers in RadioButtonList. Values are coming from database. and I'm changing RadioButtonList dynamically but if i select one answer and click on next button and then go back by pressing previous button my selection disappear. so for that i have a logic that is to store selected index in an int array and on next and previous button call that index value and put into in SelectedIndex struck of RadioButtonList. so please help me out that how can i take this selected value in an int array on OnSelectionChange? and one more addition is that i make Post Back True of RadioButtonList.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to store the selections in an array, or check the selection against an array of correct answers?

Comment: Just Want To store in to an array. no comparison Needed

Answer (score 1):

If you're populating your control dynamically, which from what I can gather you are, you will want to consider how you're going to persist values throughout the "user journey". If everything is being calculated on a single page, you can use the `ViewState` to persist information. Within a `Control`, such as a `Page` or `UserControl` you can do:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the answers to the view state
/// </summary>
private List<int> Answers
{
    get
    {
        // attempt to load the answers from the view state
        var viewStateAnswers = ViewState["Answers"];

        // if the answers are null, or not a list, create a new list and save to viewstate
        if (viewStateAnswers  == null || !(viewStateAnswers  is List<int>))
        {
            Answers = new List<int>();
        }

        // return the answers list
        return (List<int>)viewStateAnswers;
    }
    set
    {
        // saves a list to the view state
        var viewStateAnswers = ViewState["Answers"];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: I think this is the best answer, but I don't believe a setter should be needed in this case.

Comment: Hello, I'm Doing this type of dynamic Management i just Clear The Items On Next Button and load new item from database. this what i called dynamic sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem that you are instantiating each page load / posctback a new instance of the array, all page variables dies after Page UnLoad happens. So each time button click event has been fired you got a postback - a new instance of the page class is created and all underlying fields are instantiated as well.

Obviously you have to cache intermediate results, for such small amount of data (few items array) you can consider session. Also consider using generic `List<>` instead of array, especially when storing value types which cause boxing/unboxing.

```
class MyPage: Page
{
    private IList<int> correctAnswers;
    private readonly string cacheKey = "cachedResults";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventARgs args)
    {
       this.LoadCache();
    }

    protected void rbAnswers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {               
        if (rbAnswers.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
           // TODO: ensure there are enough allocated items
           // so indexer [] would not throw
           correctAnswers[rbAnswers.SelectedIndex] = i; 
           this.SyncCache();
        }
    }

    private LoadCache()
    {
       var resultsCache = Session[this.cacheKey];
       if (resultsCache != null)
       {
          this.correctAnswers = resultsCache as List<int>;
       }
    }

    private void SyncCache()
    {
        Session[this.cacheKey] = this.correctAnswers;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hello sll, I'm making it above the page-load event so is it count as page-load variable? secondly your session idea is prominent but how can i make session for every answer? or is there any other way to manage session? sorry but I'm new in .Net and its a institute project

Comment: See updated answer, bacially just keep all list in the session, this is fine for list of numbers (not very large object)

Comment: @sll: While I appreciate your effort to reuse OP's code, there are some obvious errors in the above code. Fix it so it compiles and I'll upvote.